# angular trim http:// https:// from input

Tags: javascript, angular

Hope this is a simple one. I have an input box and I am looking to use angular to trim out if a user writes http:// or https:// with their domain name in the input box.

Simple input box here it is.

```
<input type="text" id="website" name="website"  class="form-control" style='margin:0'>
```

if angular is not the best option how can I do it using javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While this is not elegant, it will satisfy your requirement until you figure out how to do it better than this.

You can look for http:// or https:// in a given string and call the .replace() method in javascript.

```
var url = "http://www.foo.com";

url.replace("http://", "");

this will return www.foo.com
```

You can also try .slice or regex

Comment: how would I apply that to a particular input box?

Comment: Use User input https://angular.io/guide/user-input or Template Driven Form https://angular.io/guide/forms or something!!

Comment: you create a function - and invoke it on ngChange or use the approach listed above by @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

found this answer hope it helps others.

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
   $("#url").change(
       function()
       {
           var textbox = $(this);
           if (textbox.val().indexOf("http://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(7));
       });
});
$(document).ready(
function()
{
   $("#url").change(
       function()
       {
           var textbox = $(this);
           if (textbox.val().indexOf("https://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(8));
       });
});
```

Comment: use Angular, not jQuery